# Should I Use 3/4 Inch Tongue and Groove OSB for Exterior Sheathing

Tags: exterior, subfloor, plywood, sheathing

I've recently built an addition and over ordered sub floor so the result is I have enough sub floor *(3/4" tongue and groove OSB)* to do a good amount of exterior sheathing.

**My question however, should I?** Are there consequences other than the sheer cost of the lumber to actually using this heavy grade of OSB on a 2x4 exterior wall or will it just produce a tighter, more insulated wall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structurally, it's not a problem. If there are windows, you may need bigger trim (surround) by 1/4". (By the way, most residential walls need to be 2x6 construction due to the energy code.)

Comment: Door jambs will be too shallow, also. I'd sell it on your local trader website and use 7/16.